# How to link two records in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want co calculate a profit, where BOTH transaction types (placed(1) and won(2) or cancel(3) ) were in the specified time period or there was only placed transaction.

Here's the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    transaction_id integer,
    reference_id integer,
    customer_id integer,
    amount integer,
    transaction_date date,
    transaction_type integer

);
```

With the following data:

```
INSERT INTO transactions 
 VALUES
(1,1, 100, 8,'2019-01-04',1),
(2,1, 100, 12,'2019-01-05',2),
(3,2, 100, 20,'2019-01-05',1),
(4,2, 100, 20,'2019-01-06',3),
(5,3, 101, 11,'2019-01-05',1),
(6,3, 101, 32,'2019-01-05',2),
(7,4, 102, 7,'2019-01-04',1),
(8,4, 102, 14,'2019-01-06',2),
(9,5, 102, 8,'2019-01-02',1),
(10,5, 102, 8,'2019-01-04',3),
(11,6, 102, 20,'2019-01-06',1),
(12,7, 103, 25,'2019-01-06',1),
(13,8, 103, 10,'2019-01-06',1),
(14,9, 103, 5,'2019-01-01',1),
(15,10, 103, 40,'2019-01-06',1);
```

And the attempted query:

```
select customer_id, sum(won-placed+cancel) as profit
from
(select customer_id, 
 sum(case when transaction_type = 1 then amount else 0 END) AS placed,
 sum(case when transaction_type = 2 then amount else 0 END) AS won,
 sum(case when transaction_type = 3 then amount else 0 END) AS cancel
 from transactions
 where transaction_date > '2019-01-04'

group by 1) x

group by 1 order by 1
```

In this case for example for customer 100, profit should be equal 0, because should be counted only from `reference_id = 2` as `transaction_id = 1` was placed before given time range.

Customer 200, profit should be -20, as there was only one `transaction_type = 1` after given time range.

I'm out of ideas how to link each transaction by its reference id, will much appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: customer 100 has records >2019-01-04' so how profit will be 0

Comment: (2,1, 100, 12,'2019-01-05',2),
(3,2, 100, 20,'2019-01-05',1),
(4,2, 100, 20,'2019-01-06',3) all these records are >>2019-01-04

Comment: Because there's `transaction_type 1` for 20 (credit) then `transaction_type 3` for same amount (debit)

And you didn't read my description well, `transaction_types 2 and 3` should be counted only when `transaction_type = 1`  was also in the specified time range

Comment: in that case 12-20-20 =12 how it will be 0

Comment: 12 shouldn't be counted because corresponding transaction (linked by reference_id = 1) was on 2019-01-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36fccd045968748652337872a5b8f99b)**

```
 select customer_id, sum(won-placed+cancel) as profit
from
(select customer_id, 
 sum(case when transaction_type = 1 then amount else 0 END) AS placed,
 sum(case when transaction_type = 2 then amount else 0 END) AS won,
 sum(case when transaction_type = 3 then amount else 0 END) AS cancel
 from transactions a
 where transaction_date > '2019-01-04' and 
 exists  (select 1 from transactions b where a.customer_id=b.customer_id
and  b.transaction_date > '2019-01-04')
and  not exists 
     (select 1 from transactions c where 
     a.customer_id=c.customer_id and transaction_date < '2019-01-05' 
     and a.reference_id=c.reference_id)
group by 1) x
group by 1 order by 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
customer_id profit
   100           0
   101          -21
   102          -6
   103          -75
```

Comment: Somewhere close, but it gives wrong value for example for 103, result should be -65

Comment: @sh4rkyy, could u please explain how it be -65

Comment: Sorry, mistake :D -75 of course, all transaction_type 1 are after 2019-01-04 and should be counted

Comment: Now customer 102 has wrong result, should be - 20
I tried this one, and it works, however its terribly slow and inefficient on bigger database :(

`where transaction_date > '2019-01-04' and reference_id not in (select reference_id from transactions b where a.customer_id=b.customer_id and transaction_date < '2019-01-05')` - I

Comment: @sh4rkyy, I've updated the answer with exists operator - you can check how if perform